# Scrapy not printing attribute errors

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

This issue has been highlighted by a [github_user](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3161).Can anyone help how to extract the attribute errors using scrapy without using Django or other tools?Thank You in advance.

Comment: The original error was because of misconfigured logging. Do you modify any logging handlers? Do you import any modules that do?

Comment: Thank You for responding.I regenerated the same error on local machine without altering any logging handlers and didnot imported any modules.

Comment: Without a self-contained example, it's hard to see what the problem is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725800/scrapy-not-printing-out-stacktrace-on-exception

May be this can help you understand what the problem is

Comment: You're not using django, so that doesn't really explain much. Make a copy of your project and start removing code until you get a minimal working example.